# connecting UINavigaitionController to the delegate in Interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, interface-builder

Is it the correct to connect the UINavigationController outlets to the AppDelegate?
I have declared the NavigationController in the app delegate so I am pretty sure this is the correct corse of action but I'm just wanting confirmation or advice on why it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I think, you are trying to connect `delegate` to `Navigation Controller`. You should not add `delegate` for `navigationController`.

If you are using **iOS 5** then, you can just drag and drop the `navigationController` in storyboard.

In **iOS 4**, you have to give `outlet` and `synthesize` it and then add `navigationController` into `subview` for `window`. thats it.

You don't need to add `delegate` for `navigationController` anytime.

Answer (score 1):

No..It's not correct. You dont required to connect the delegate to the navigation controller. Instead You should give outlet , synthesize it and add navigation controller into your subview.